# Laravel add condition inside model public function relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am developing a booking system which used Laravel 7.0

so in this system I created a table called 'bookings'

and I created its model called Booking.php

inside this Booking.php I put in relation function to join its model to transaction table like below

```
public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Transaction', 'id', 'booking_id');
    }
```

suddenly a new requirement coming in, and this booking will have its child

so to differentiate between the booking parent and its child i am adding a new column to the booking table called

'parent_booking_id'

I don't want to change the code function too much so I am thinking on making condition to make sure the relation of the booking points to the correct transaction

I am thinking of code like this to be written

```
public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Transaction', 'parent_booking_id' ?? 'id', 'booking_id');
    }
```

but it is not working as intended

the logic is

If the parent_booking_id exists then join the 'booking_id' column at table transaction to 'parent_booking_id' column at table bookings

else

it will join the 'booking_id' column at table transaction to 'id' column at table bookings

Comment: yes its obvious that it doesnt work since `'parent_booking_id'` is a string and will therefore always be the argument. You might try `$this->parent_booking_id ? 'x' : 'y'` but it might even be better to create 2 relations for clarity purposes

Comment: have tried $this->parent_booking_id, but it always return null so cannot use as conditional, how do I create 2 relations without changing current code  that already use the transaction function

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I understood everything.

I not using that kind of logic inside models, but if you really want it. I'm not sure, but I think this could work.

```
 public function parent_booking()
 {
     $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Booking', 'parent_booking_id');
 }

 public function transaction()
 {
     if ($this->has('parent_booking')) {
          return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Transaction', 'parent_booking_id', 'booking_id');
     } else {
          return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Transaction', 'booking_id');
     }
 }
```

If ywhat you try to achieve is this:
When a booking have a parent_booking, attach the transaction to the parent_booking, else, attach it to the booking.

To do this, my suggestion is to do things more like this.

```
 public function parent_booking()
 {
     $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Booking', 'parent_booking_id');
 }

 public function childs_booking()
 {
     $this->hasMany('App\Models\Booking', 'parent_booking_id');
 }
```

Then, you can do this in controller:

```
$booking = Booking::with('parent_booking')->find($id);
if ($booking->has('parent_booking')) {
    //do some stuff.
    $booking->parent_booking->transaction->associate($transaction->id);
} else {
    //do other stuff
    $booking->transaction->associate($transaction->id);
}
```

And for sure, you will want to retrieve the right transaction. There is an example on a retrieve of every bookings.

```
$bookings = Booking::with(array('parent_booking', function($query) {
    return $query->with('transaction');
}))->with('transaction')->get();

foreach($bookings as $booking) {
    if ($booking->has('parent_booking')) {
        $transaction_to_use = $booking->parent_booking->transaction;
    } else {
        $transaction_to_use = $booking->transaction;
    }
}
```

You can also perform something like this:

```
$transactions = Transaction::with(array('booking', function($query) {
    return $query->with('childs_booking');
}))->get();
```

This way you get every transactions with their booking. You also have every child booking.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to this problem

the proper way to fix this is by

making 2 relation

and then altering code using where condition to make sure it pass the correct relation based on booking value

**BUT** because this way of fixing require to much code changes i try to find other ways

and the other ways is to instead of creating 'parent_booking_id' i create a column called 'primary_booking_id'

this 'primary_booking_id' will always contain the booking_id of the first booking being made

so on first time create the model I will update so that it gains the booking_id

```
$booking->update(['primary_booking_id' => $booking->id]);
```

and then during creation of its child I will put into the primary_booking_id into the creation

```
$input['primary_booking_id'] => $previous_booking->primary_booking_id;

$booking::create($input);
```

so the way this is handled require to make just minor changes to booking transaction relation function as below

```
public function transaction()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Transaction', 'booking_id', 'primary_booking_id');
}
```

voila!

it works and no major changes involve